# keep observableArrays sorted after push

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, knockout.js

I have two observable arrays, and I need to remove elements from the first one and push to the second one and vice versa. But when I do so, the alphabetical sorting is messed up.

```
self.allCourses = ko.observableArray([]);
self.selectedCourses = ko.observableArray([]);
```

I will interchange courses between the two arrays, and using this :

```
self.sortArrays = function(){
    self.allCourses.sort(function (l, r) {
        return  l.code() < r.code() ;
    });
    self.selectedCourses.sort(function (l, r) {
        return  l.code() < r.code() ;
    });
}
```

not only is it not efficient, but also doesnt work as expected ;I call the function each time I call one of these functions

```
self.addCourse = function(course){
    self.selectedCourses.push(course);
    self.allCourses.remove(course);
     self.sortArrays();
};
self.removeCourse = function(course){
    self.allCourses.push(course);
    self.selectedCourses.remove(course);
     self.sortArrays();
};
```

Comment: Why are your removing course while adding and vice versa?

Comment: Returning a `<` in a `sort` function is never gonna work as expected. You are supposed to return a positive, 0, or negative value.

Comment: these are majors, so i'm actually filling courses in the major, and vice versa to remove them from the major

Comment: @Isac this might be a good note to take into consideration, but even if this one works, it still is time consuming, especially when having lots of courses

Answer (score 3):

I would consider two approaches.

1. Keep your data always sorted.  Instead of calling `.sort()`, search for the right location to put the element, and call `.splice()` to insert it in the right place.  This is a `O(n)` algorithm, but should be fast in practice.
2. Use something like https://libraries.io/npm/dsjslib to maintain a sorted data structure at all times.  This makes insert/delete a `O(log(n))` operation.  However every operation now has extra complexity.

Which one to use will depend on whether your operations are dominated by the effort of insert/delete, or by running through the list and displaying it.  My best guess is that running through the list and displaying it matters more.

Furthermore the next question is whether it is better to do the search by scanning through the array, or by binary search.  Scanning is `O(n)` but branch prediction mistakes cost so much that I've seen it be faster than binary search for inserting into lists of hundreds of elements.

Answer (score 3):

Using knockout, u can also create computed based on your observable array, so you always will have sorted array

```
self.allCoursesSorted = ko.computed(function(){
    return this.allCourses.sort(function (l, r) {
       return  l.code() < r.code() ;
    });
}, this);
```

for selected courses you can use same approach but with filter

```
self.allCoursesSelected = ko.computed(function(){
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.allCoursesSorted(), 
        function (item) {
            return item.selected === true;
        });
}, this);
```

Answer (score 2):

When removing an item from an array, you will never have to do a re-sort.

Instead of *pushing* and re-sorting, you could insert an item using your sort definition.

You'll only need to define the sorted inject function, since knockout observable arrays already have a `remove` method:

```js
const sorter = (a, b) => a > b ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : 0;

const leftNumbers = ko.observableArray(
  [3,5,1,2].sort(sorter)
);
const rightNumbers = ko.observableArray(
  [4,1,3,5].sort(sorter)
);

// There are many ways to write this function, which you can probable
// find on stack overflow. The destructuring probably makes this slower
// than just re-sorting. I'll leave it up to you to optimize for performance.
const injectSorted = (sorter, arr, nr) => {
  const pos = arr.findIndex(x => sorter(x, nr) > -1);

  if (pos === -1) return arr.concat(nr);
  
  return [
    ...arr.slice(0, pos),
    nr,
    ...arr.slice(pos)
  ];
};

// Notice how we don't need to re-sort
const moveFromTo = (arr1, arr2) => x => {
  arr2(injectSorted(sorter, arr2(), arr1.remove(x)));
};

ko.applyBindings({ leftNumbers, rightNumbers, moveFromTo });
```

```css
div { display: flex; justify-content: space-around; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<p>Click numbers to move between lists</p>
<div>
  <ul data-bind="foreach: leftNumbers">
    <li data-bind="click: moveFromTo(leftNumbers, rightNumbers), text: $data"></li>
  </ul>
  <ul data-bind="foreach: rightNumbers">
    <li data-bind="click: moveFromTo(rightNumbers, leftNumbers), text: $data"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```